# How to change sonarqube projectversion number automatically in jenkins

Tags: c#, jenkins, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I'm using the "SonarScanner for MSBuild for Jenkins" and i'm trying to change sonarQube projectVersion number automatically.

I have a windows system variable that contains the number that i want put in this window.
I try in many diferents ways (with no success):

```
ProjectVersion: %MY_GLOBAL_VARIABLE% 
ProjectVersion: MY_GLOBAL_VARIABLE
ProjectVersion: ${%MY_GLOBAL_VARIABLE%}
ProjectVersion: ${MY_GLOBAL_VARIABLE}
```

Does anyone knows how can I call this variable? Its possible do that using this Jenkins' block?

It works If I put the function in a Windows batch command, but I loose links that is show in Jenkins' main page.
CODE:

```
G:\jenkins-slave\tools\hudson.plugins.sonar.MsBuildSQRunnerInstallation\sonar\SonarScanner.MSBuild.exe begin 
/k:"key" 
/n:"name" 
/v:%MY_GLOBAL_VARIABLE%
```

Image shows the variable that I'm telling you about and Link that I loose if I use a Windows batch command
[image: Image shows the variable that I'm telling you about and Link that I loose if I use a Windows batch command]
[UPDATE]
SonarQube Version:
[image: SonarVersionMaven]
[image: SonarVersion]

Comment: Which version of [SonarQube Scanner for Jenkins](http://redirect.sonarsource.com/plugins/jenkins.html) do you use?

Comment: @agabrys i'm using 2.164.1

Comment: I asked for the SonarQube plugin version, not the Jenkins version.

Comment: @agabrys its SonarScanner for MSBuild 4.6 and SonarQube Scanner 3.3.0.1492

Comment: Non of those two are SonarQube Jenkins plugin. I need to know the version of [SonarQube Scanner for Jenkins](https://plugins.jenkins.io/sonar) (at this moment the latest is 2.8.1).

Comment: @agabrys those are the versions I have. I updated the question with a screen-shot.

Comment: I understand that you have those versions, but I asked for a version of [SonarQube Scanner for Jenkins](http://redirect.sonarsource.com/plugins/jenkins.html) plugin. It is a different tool. You have to open `Manage Jenkins → Manage Plugins → Installed`, and search for `SonarQube Scanner for Jenkins` (or easier version `<your-jenkins-url>pluginManager/plugin/sonar/thirdPartyLicenses`) and past its version.

Comment: @agabrys Finally I have the SonarQube Scanner for Jenkins plugin version. Its 2.8.1. I added the image above.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Jenkins documentation](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Building+a+software+project#Buildingasoftwareproject-ShellScriptsandWindowsBatchCommands) you should use on:

- Linux/Unix: `${MY_GLOBAL_VARIABLE}` or `$MY_GLOBAL_VARIABLE`
- Windows: `%MY_GLOBAL_VARIABLE%`

[SonarQube Scanner for Jenkins](http://redirect.sonarsource.com/plugins/jenkins.html) has supported using environment variables since version 2.5 (see [SONARJNKNS-267 Support using env variable to configure Scanner for MSBuild](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARJNKNS-267)), so it should be possible to use environment variables.

Are you sure this environment variable is set? Could you execute `Execute Windows batch command` step before `SonarScanner for MSBuild - Begin Analysis` and verify that the variable is set properly:

```
echo %MY_GLOBAL_VARIABLE%
```